# How to style stackplot color in pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to work out how to style a stacked bar chart in Pandas.

I've written a line of code in a Jupyter notebook which produces a plot like below. So far so simple:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked=True, color=['green', 'blue'], legend=None)
```

However, I want to change the colours to be almost hex like, but the API won't accept that.

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked=True, color=['green', '#ccc'], legend=None)
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: '#'
```

Then tried the hex to RGBA converter: http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/

But the values it returns aren't in range. What's the best, most pythonic way to convert to RGBA values of 0-1 that Matplotlib seems to want, as I'll need to do this a lot.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is that you are using a three letter Hex code shorthand instead of the standard 6 letter code. Using '#cccccc' works fine for me.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen You're right. Add it as an answer and I'll give you plaudits. Wasted two hours on this. :)

Comment: It is always the small things that lead to longest bug hunts. FYI, I just checked on the matplotlib github issues page, and [it looks like version 3.2 supports hex code short hands](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/15152). So upgrading might solve your problem with shorthands. Don't worry about my points, I have plenty (but thank you).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @PaulBrodersen. Turns out I needed to use full six-digit hex code such as #ccccccc rather than shorthand although latest version of Matplotlib 3.2 does support short codes. Thank you.